# Generate 1 Excel-file with two tabs from two input file in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pdi

I am trying to develop a job that is able to generate 1 Excel-file with two tabs. Basically, what I want to achieve is:

tab 1 is based on input file 1
tab 2 is based on input file 2

I have two input file which contain different query, but end result should be in one excel file with two tab ,one tab for first input and second for input 2.

Answer (score 2):

One way of achieving this would be a Pentaho Job with two transformations that are processed in order. Only the first transformation creates/overwrites the Excel file in the `Microsoft Excel Writer` step.

1. Create a transformation that processes data from input file 1
2. Create a "Microsoft Excel Writer" Step.
3. Set the `If output file exists` option to overwrite.
4. Create the second transformation to process data from input file 2
5. Create a "Microsoft Excel Writer" step with the same file settings as in the first transformation, **but**
6. Set the `If output file exists` option to "Use existing file for writing"
7. Create a job and include the two transformations, make sure the transformation
   for the input file1 comes first.

That should do the job.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Could you elaborate step 7. Should i create two transformation or one transforamation?

Comment: @user6186914 Create the two transformations as described in this answer if they can be made independent. If you need to cross-reference data it's possible to do it in one transformation with a blocking step, but that's more complicated and less reliable than Arminius' answer.